# Can someone explain the difference between these css lines?

Tags: css

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}`
```

I tried removing each of these separately, and saw no difference.

Comment: do a search about each keyword and read about it

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

sets `box-sizing` to `border-box` for your root element

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

here all children, including pseudo-element, are set to inherit the `box-sizing` value (from the root element)

Read about `box-sizing` here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Most (or all?) browsers have a default margin on the body element. If your code is

```
<body>
    Some text
</body>
```

there will be a bit of space to the browsers edge. To "normalise" that and start with your design from the browsers' edges, margin gets set to `0`.